# Preserving the layer names while writing raster

Tags: r, raster

I want to preserve the names of raster layers while writing a raster stack.

I have tried with the code shown, the error is not shown with this code but the location doesn't show any files written:

```
MosaicedA<- mosaic(Stacked1A,Stacked2A, fun=mean, tolerance=0.5)
names(MosaicedA)<-c('one','Two','three')
################################################################
writeRaster(MosaicedA,filename = names(MosaicedA),bylayer=TRUE,format="ENVI",overwrite=TRUE, "C:/Users/rajeev.bhattarai/Documents/Research/Testing/Rajeev.envi" )
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a work-around function:

```
writeENVI <- function(x, f, ...) {
    writeRaster(x, f, overwrite=TRUE, ...)
    cat("band names = {", paste(names(x),collapse=","), "}", "\n", file=extension(f, "hdr"), append=TRUE)
}
```

Example data

```
library(raster)
s <- stack(system.file("external/rlogo.grd", package="raster")) 
names(s)
#[1] "red"   "green" "blue"
```

Use the function

```
writeENVI(s, "test.envi")
```

Check that it worked

```
brick(f)
#class      : RasterBrick 
#dimensions : 77, 101, 7777, 3  (nrow, ncol, ncell, nlayers)
#resolution : 1, 1  (x, y)
#extent     : 0, 101, 0, 77  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#crs        : +proj=merc +lon_0=0 +lat_ts=0 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0 
#source     : test.envi 
#names      : red, green, blue 
#min values :   0,     0,    0 
#max values : 255,   255,  255
```